# Beautiful Soup find returns [] or none

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm making my first little web scraping program. I'm trying to get the price of a product but soup.find returns "None".

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = 'https://www.pichau.com.br/placa-de-video-asus-geforce-gtx-1650-dual-4gb-gddr5-128-bit-dual-gtx1650-4g'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36 OPR/82.0.4227.50'}

page = requests.get(site, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
price = soup.find(class_ = 'jss237')

print(price)
```

This is returning None, however, if I get the class of the box that covers the entire thing, like this

```
price = soup.find(class_ = 'MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-12 MuiGrid-grid-sm-5').get_text()
```

It returns everything, including the prices that I'm trying to get

```
Placa de Video Asus GeForce GTX 1650 Dual, 4GB, GDDR5, 128-bit, DUAL-GTX1650-4G...SKU: DUAL-GTX1650-4Gà vistaR$1.989,00no PIX com 12% descontoR$ 2.260,23em até 12x de 188,35sem juros no cartão CaracterísticasGarantia: 12 Meses
```

Comment: What is your expected output / goal? Do you only want the price returned?

Answer (score 1):

The `.jsN` class names appear to be auto-generated, or subject to A/B pages, so I noticed they were changing from load to load after posting my initial answer (see the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70763126/revisions) if you want to see the old solution).

The primary price is available in the static markup as metadata:

```html
<meta property="product:price:amount" content="R$1.989,00" />
```

Select that with

```py
print(soup.select_one('[property="product:price:amount"]')['content'])
```

If you want `188,35`, you could use some nearby expected text, icon or DOM structure to identify it, or use a regex on the body text to grab price-looking substrings:

```py
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.pichau.com.br/placa-de-video-asus-geforce-gtx-1650-dual-4gb-gddr5-128-bit-dual-gtx1650-4g"
response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
body = soup.select_one("body").decode_contents()
print(re.findall(r"\b(?:\d+\.)?\d+,\d{2,}\b", body)) 
# => ['1.989,00', '2.260,23', '188,35']
```

You can be more specific than `body` to reduce false positives, at the risk of depending on that selector existing (use case dependent).

Note that I used lxml, which is faster and more adaptive than html.parser, but you can use html.parser if you don't have lxml handy.